# MySQL Help - Combining 2 MySQL Selects - Result in 1

Tags: mysql, select

I have two MySQL statements (see below), I would like to combine them together so if they both result in a 1 then the end result will be 1. I'm not sure how to construct this and was hoping for some help.

```
select count(*)
from monitor
where name='job_starttime' and value < ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( ) -600)

select count(*)
from monitor
where name='job_active' and value = 0
```

So for example I would like when both statements are true to result in a value of 1, if 1 or none are true it results in a 0.

I nearly achieved it with the below SQL (except it's giving a result for each entry in the table) :(

```
select
case
when (select count(*) from monitor
where exists (select * from monitor where name = 'job1_active' AND value = 1)
and exists (select * from monitor where name = 'job2_active' AND value = 1)) > 1
then 1
else 0
end
from monitor
```

Answer (score 0):

(I am assuming you want the result in a `WHERE` or some other place for testing?)

This is faster, but is equivalent to COUNT(*) >= 1.

```
SELECT ...
    WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM monitor
                   WHERE name = 'job_starttime' AND value < ... )
      AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM monitor
                   WHERE name = 'job_active' AND value = 0 )
```

Otherwise:

```
SELECT ...
    WHERE ( SELECT COUNT(*) ... ) = 1
      AND ( SELECT COUNT(*) ... ) = 1
```

Another tip:  `false` == 0; `true` == 1.

Comment: @ Rick James - Sorry I'm just not getting it where you mention 'Select ...' what should I replace that with?

Comment: How about `SELECT 1` - you will get either `1` or `NULL`.

Comment: So - SELECT 1
    WHERE ( SELECT COUNT(*) ... ) = 1
      AND ( SELECT COUNT(*) ... ) = 1

Comment: See if it works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately not :(, I didn't think it would be this hard to combine these select statements but it is proving difficult.

Comment: Add your attempt to the question, and explain what went wrong.

Comment: So I have tried the below and failed:-

    SELECT 1
    WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM monitor
    WHERE name = 'job1_active' AND value = 1 )
    AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM monitor
    WHERE name = 'job2_active' AND value = 1 )

Comment: And also this failed too:-

SELECT 1
    WHERE ( SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE name = 'job1_active' AND value = 1 ) = 1
      AND ( SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE name = 'job2_active' AND value = 1 ) = 1

Comment: "Failed" meaning syntax error?  Crashed?  Got "3" as a result?